# Can someone suggest a general machine vision algorithm for detecting the first edge?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

I have a need to find the leading edge in a machine vision application.  This edge can vary slightly in shape and can sometimes have lower contrast than an edge further inside the part we are measuring.

I would like to find a general algorithm I can use to find the leading edge in a region I specify, searching in a direction I specify. Lastly, this must always be a positive edge.  That is, it transitions from a dark region to a lighter region.

To be clear, I am not looking for a edge detection algorithm, like Canny.  I want help on the general approach to selecting the right edges in my image that fit within an ROI and match the polarity constraints.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:
[image]

Comment: What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector

Answer (score 1):

The [Canny feature detection](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny) of `opencv` does the job. Extract features, and later you can filter them however you want (e.g. the transistion, direction, etc.)

Comment: I think with Canny uses a LoG filter in x and y axes.  Will the direction information be valid, if the edge is at 45 degrees, for instance?

Comment: Yes, that algorithm is rotation invariant.

Comment: The edge detection algorithm is not the problem.  I am wondering about a general approach to identifying the leading edge in this region of interest.  Once I find the edges, now I have an array of edge points.  Can you think of an elegant approach to searching along these vectors (2) in the ROI (1)?  I was thinking of calculating the perpendicular distance from the edge point the each vector, then selecting points within some distance threshold, then closest to the start of the vector (left side).